# Unable to download Application on ipad2

Tags: iphone, iis

I am facing a problem for the last couple of days regarding the downloading of the application  on ipad.

What I have done is hosted the .ipa and .plist on my IIS server and installed the certificates on the server. Actually i am giving the https link for downloading the application.

Whenever,the service is hit from the ipad end,sometimes the error occurs:"Cannot connect to the server or otherwise unable to download at this time and retry many times"  but not able to download

I am sending the code for .plist file and the html on which we are calling the .plist  file.

Code for plist Section:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

<key>items</key>

<array>

<dict>

<key>assets</key>

<array>

<dict>

<key>kind</key>

<string>software-package</string>

<key>url</key>

<string>https://<ServerName>:<PortNumber>/abcV.ipa</string>

</dict>

</array>

<key>metadata</key>

<dict>

<key>bundle-identifier</key>

<string>abc</string>

<key>bundle-version</key>

<string>1.0</string>

<key>kind</key>

<string>software</string>

<key>subtitle</key>

<string>abcV.25</string>

<key>title</key>

<string>abcV.25</string>

</dict>

</dict>

</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am calling the itms services in the body as:

```
 <a href="itms-services://?action=download- manifest&url=https://<ServerIP>:<PortNumber>/abc.plist">Install the app</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using normal http instead of https?

Also, When I have used java web services, the url will be

http://:port//abcV.ipa

Jus check appending the projectName path component after  this `http://<serverIP>:port/`

Also, write a sample html and check if that is opening or not.

Comment: It was working fine with http and with the same URL.The only difference we have made is, now we use https in the path instead of http

Comment: Please tell me one thing the certificates need to be installed on both server side and ipad as well or only at the server end

Comment: We are able to download the .ipa and .plist files from server

Comment: We have tried installing certificates on the ipad still "unable to download" error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a space in the URL. The certificates need to be installed only on the iOS Device side. If that doesn't work, what is wrong here is probably your MIME types. Check the Apple Docs for more in-depth info about MIME types for itms-services://